# Dynamically add event to custom control (Confirm Message Box)

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, messagebox, dopostback

I have created a custom cofirm message box control and I created an event like this-

```
[Category("Action")]
[Description("Raised when the user clicks the button(ok)")]
    public event EventHandler Submit;

protected virtual void OnSubmit(EventArgs e) {
     if (Submit != null)
        Submit(this, e);
}
```

The Event OnSubmit occurs when  user click the OK button on the Confrim Box.

```
void IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    OnSubmit(e);
}
```

Now I am adding this OnSubmit Event Dynamically like this-
In aspx-

```
<my:ConfirmMessageBox ID="cfmTest" runat="server" ></my:ConfirmMessageBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCallMsg" runat="server" onclick="btnCallMsg_Click" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtResult" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

In cs-

```
protected void btnCallMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  cfmTest.Submit += cfmTest_Submit;//Dynamically Add Event
  cfmTest.ShowConfirm("Are you sure to Save Data?");  //Show Confirm Message using Custom Control Message Box
}

    protected void cfmTest_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //..Some Code..
          //..
          txtResult.Text = "User Confirmed";//I set the text to "User Confrimed" but it's not displayed
          txtResult.Focus();//I focus the textbox but I got Error
        }
```

The Error I got is-
**System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message="SetFocus can only be called before and during PreRender."
  Source="System.Web"**

So, when I dynamically add and fire custom control's event, there is an error in Web Control.
If I add event in aspx file like this,

```
<my:ConfirmMessageBox ID="cfmTest" runat="server" OnSubmit="cfmTest_Submit"></my:ConfirmMessageBox>
```

There is no error and work fine.

Can anybody help me to add event dynamically to custom control?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the combination of the event being added late in the life cycle, and what you are trying to achieve with event handler.

As the error clearly states, the problem is with this line:

```
txtResult.Focus();
```

If you want to be able to set focus to controls, you must add your event handler on `Init` or `Load`.

You can work around this problem by setting the focus at client side using jquery.

```
var script = "$('#"+txtResult.ClientID+"').focus();";
```

You would have to emit this using [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx).

Comment: Where can I add event dynamically ?

Comment: You can add events on clicks, nothing wrong with that. Just don't focus on them.

Comment: Did you mean, I should work the web controls(textbox..) at Client side only?

Comment: It(RegisterClientScriptBlock) is not work in this event(cfmTest_Submit) but work in other event (button_click)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change would be to move the focus() call:

```
bool focusResults = false;

    protected void cfmTest_Sumit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      txtResult.Text = "User Confirmed";
     focusResults = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnPreRender(e);

        if(focusResults)
           txtResult.Focus();
    }
```

Are you sure txtResult.Text isn't being set again somewhere else?

Comment: If I added the event in aspx file (not dynamically),it displayed the Text in txtResult properly.

Comment: When you add it to aspx, these eventhandlers are added when the controls are created, usually on `Init`.